# How To Connect Web3 With MetaMask?

Tags: web3js, truffle, metamask

No tutorial can help me, I have watched almost every major tutorial on Youtube and read a ton of results from Google...

I have on my HTML file imported the web3.min.js (copied from Truffle pet-shop because web3 does not come with this anymore!)

And then on a script tag below that, for testing, I manage to connect it with Metamask, I thin, with

```
    window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  if (typeof Web3 !== 'undefined') {
    web3js = new Web3(Web3.currentProvider);
  } else {
    console.log('No web3? You should consider trying MetaMask!');
    web3js = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:8545'));
  }
});
```

But still `Web3.eth` is undefined, so I can't connect to a contract or make calls.

Can anyone help me with the basic steps to interact with the contract from a front end?...

Answer (score 12):

The Metamask interface has changed to enable privacy and consent from the user before allowing any access to the account information contained within Metamask. This is done by injecting an "ethereum" object to the browser window. You must now wait for the ethereum.enable() function to return true after prompting the user. More details here: https://medium.com/metamask/https-medium-com-metamask-breaking-change-injecting-web3-7722797916a8

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
 // Wait for loading completion to avoid race conditions with web3 injection timing.
  if (window.ethereum) {
    const web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);
    try {
      // Request account access if needed
      await window.ethereum.enable();
      // Accounts now exposed
      return web3;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }
  // Legacy dapp browsers...
  else if (window.web3) {
    // Use MetaMask/Mist's provider.
    const web3 = window.web3;
    console.log('Injected web3 detected.');
    return web3;
  }
  // Fallback to localhost; use dev console port by default...
  else {
    const provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://127.0.0.1:9545');
    const web3 = new Web3(provider);
    console.log('No web3 instance injected, using Local web3.');
    return web3;
  }
});
```

Comment: you have to declare the anonymous function as async

Comment: Guys this is the most valuable post on stackExchange .
But only one thing who can i load a contract istance , because the :
if (window.ethereum) {
    const web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);
}
web3 object doesnt have the eth object to load a contract and make a call , pleaseeeeeeeeeee help !
I need to achieve this :
 addresss = new window.web3.eth.Contract(abi, contractAddress);

Answer (score 8):

You are mixing capital case **Web3** with small case **web3**. `Web3.eth` does not exist.

Try the following:

```
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
        web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
    } else {
        console.log('No web3? You should consider trying MetaMask!');
        web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:8545'));
    }
});
```

now you can write something like `web3.eth`.

Answer (score 2):

window.web3 is removed by metamask. now everything can be done with window.ethereum - [web3 removal link by metamask](https://docs.metamask.io/guide/provider-migration.html#summary-of-breaking-changes)

Below is the new way of getting accounts.

```
import detectEthereumProvider from '@metamask/detect-provider';
```

initialize ethereum provider

```
async loadWeb3() {
const provider = await detectEthereumProvider()

if (provider) {
  console.log('Ethereum successfully detected!')
  // From now on, this should always be true:
  // provider === window.ethereum

  // Access the decentralized web!

  // Legacy providers may only have ethereum.sendAsync
  const chainId = await provider.request({
    method: 'eth_chainId'
  })
} else {
  // if the provider is not detected, detectEthereumProvider resolves to null
  console.error('Please install MetaMask!' )
}
}
```

Here is how you can access the accounts:

```
async loadWeb3Accounts() {
const accounts = await window.ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' });
console.log(accounts[0]);}
```

Comment: Guys this is the most valuable post on stackExchange . But only one thing who can i load a contract istance , because the :
 if (window.ethereum) { const web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum); } 
web3 object doesnt have the eth object to load a contract and make a call , pleaseeeeeeeeeee help ! 
I need to achieve this : addresss = new window.web3.eth.Contract(abi, contractAddress); 

please i need to detect it on mobile and make a contract transaction

Answer (score 1):

MetaMask is not only kind of the wallet anymore. There is now more generic Web3modal solution that allows e.g. mobile wallets to connect with your dApp. It supports both web MetaMask and MetaMask mobile via WalletConnect protocol:

https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/82532/620