# How do I make my smart contract available for interaction with Metamask?

Tags: web3js, metamask, contract-invocation, web3-providers

I am using OpenZeppelin starter kit. I wrote a smart contract that simply contains two integers which can be called. I compiled and deployed the smart contract to my local Ganache blockchain. I have started my React Dapp and it's connected to Ganache through Metamask (I can see my account balance for example).

Please see my repository: https://github.com/Lennardmulder/ozreact

I now want my Dapp to have a button that allows the user to call the `count` function and show its results. I suspect I first need to use something like

```
var myContract = new web3.eth.Contract([...], '0xde0B295669a9FD93d5F28D9Ec85E40f4cb697BAe', {
    from: '0x1234567890123456789012345678901234567891', // default from address
    gasPrice: '20000000000' // default gas price in wei, 20 gwei in this case
});
```

With the right ABI and address inserted, to allow Metamask to interact with the smart contract? But where exactly do I define this in my code?

Answer (score 0):

Taking a look at your smart contract [here](https://github.com/Lennardmulder/ozreact/blob/master/contracts/numbercall.sol) I don't see a getter method where your dApp can point to. In your smart contract place this code:

```
function getCount() public view returns(uint) {
    return count;
}
```

Now in your dApp you can access this new method like this:

```
myContract.methods.getCount().call({from: <ADDRESS>}, function(err, response) {
    if(!err) {
        console.log(response, 'response');
    } else {
        console.error(err, 'err');
    }
});
```

Also when upgrading and redeploying your contract don't forget to replace the contract address at `new web3.eth.Contract()`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Actually I believe solidity 0.6.0 creates a getter method automatically when you define a public uint256. You can test this by copy pasting the numbercall.sol contract in Remix.

As for the second part of your answer, I think this will not work if I don't first specify myContract, with the corresponding ABI + address of the contract right? My question is more about where and how to specify this code.

Comment: Correct, ```myContract.methods.getCount().``` won't work if you don't create ```myContract``` instance with your smart contract address and abi definition. You can take the abi definition from remix before deployment and after the contract deployment you can take the address.

Comment: My JS file now contains a contract object as you instructed. My chrome browser loads the file just fine, but when I try to interact with the contract through the JS console by typing `numberCall.methods.count.call();` it throws `VM6138:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: numberCall is not defined`. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

To add to Miroslav's answer (sorry, I can't comment yet):

If you define your variable as public, the compiler will automatically generate a getter method with the same name as the variable. `uint public count` as declared in OPs contract will generate the function

```
function count() public view returns(uint) {
    return count;
}
```

There is no need to manually create a getter, just use `const count = await instance.methods.count().call()` inside an async function to get the value of count.

Take a look here to see how to connect web3 with metamask: [How To Connect Web3 With MetaMask?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/67145/how-to-connect-web3-with-metamask)