# Ethereum not defined error

Tags: web3js, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I'm trying to use the following piece of code to build an De-Fi App by following along this tutorial

Following is the piece of code in the App.js file

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Web3 from 'web3'
import logo from '../logo.png';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  async componentWillMount(){
    await this.loadWeb3()
    console.log(window.web3)
  }
  async loadWeb3(){
    window.addEventListener('load', async () => {
      // Modern dapp browsers...
      if (window.ethereum) {
          window.web3 = new Web3(ethereum);
          try {
              // Request account access if needed
              await ethereum.enable();
              // Acccounts now exposed
              web3.eth.sendTransaction({/* ... */});
          } catch (error) {
              // User denied account access...
          }
      }
```

However I'm getting the following error when I try to run it in the Chrome browser where Metamask

> 'ethereum' is not defined  no-undef

I was merely following the tutorial on [Blockchain App tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VH9Q2lf2mNo&t=5779s) and the step is around the 1 hour 38 minute mark.

Answer (score 1):

original answer from Do hoang
[How To Connect Web3 With MetaMask?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/67145/how-to-connect-web3-with-metamask/78987?newreg=ff0237eeab364ef7a7a5bb6aae529045)

Metamask privacy changed. so we have to wait for the eth to enable. Try this below code and it worked for me.

```
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
 // Wait for loading completion to avoid race conditions with web3 injection timing.
  if (window.ethereum) {
    const web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);
    try {
      // Request account access if needed
      await window.ethereum.enable();
      // Acccounts now exposed
      return web3;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }
  // Legacy dapp browsers...
  else if (window.web3) {
    // Use Mist/MetaMask's provider.
    const web3 = window.web3;
    console.log('Injected web3 detected.');
    return web3;
  }
  // Fallback to localhost; use dev console port by default...
  else {
    const provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://127.0.0.1:9545');
    const web3 = new Web3(provider);
    console.log('No web3 instance injected, using Local web3.');
    return web3;
  }
});
```