# 'web3' is not defined no-undef even after importing

Tags: solidity, web3js, ethereumjs, react, web3-providers

I imported web3 but why this annoying error is occurring please help me...

i imported like this

```
import Web3 from 'web3'
```

and the error is occurring here

```
this.web3Provider = web3.currentProvider
```

Comment: Did you initialize Web3?You gave me too little code to analyze. 

Comment: yes, please share more code

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem trying to connect my website to metamask. If thats your case too, check this out -> [How To Connect Web3 With MetaMask?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/67145/how-to-connect-web3-with-metamask/78987#78987)

PS you should edit the code after 'load', and add async