# const web3Obj = new web3(window.ethereum) is not working

Tags: web3js

I have searched this and can't understand what is problem at my side. Please suggest. Thanks in advance.

## index.html

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./index.js"> </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./node_modules/web3/dist/web3.min.js"> 
    </script>
```

## index.js

const web3Obj = new web3(window.ethereum);
console.log(web3Obj);

## Error

index.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: web3 is not a constructor
at index.js:1:17

## Operating System

Ubuntu

Comment: Are you using const web3Obj = new web3(window.ethereum)? Pay attention to the lower case in "new web3", it should be "new Web3" (upper case W)

Comment: try this instead `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/web3@1.7.1/lib/index.min.js`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple potential issues/solutions here:

1. Your JS is loading out of order. If you are loading the web3 library after index.js, then index.js doesn't know what web3 is because it hasn't loaded yet. Remember that in the browser, JS files are loaded/executed in the order listed. You could also `import` or `require` the web3 object using the second listed JS file, rather than importing it via a `<script>` tag
2. Metamask (or other wallet provider/web3 injector) is not installed in the browser you're using
3. Your issue can probably be answered by these questions: [How To Connect Web3 With MetaMask?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/67145/how-to-connect-web3-with-metamask/78987#78987) or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65802366/metamask-does-not-inject-window-ethereum-uncaught-in-promise-typeerror-canno

Comment: Thanks a lot this resolves the issue.

Comment: boss kindly look at this question also:
https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/125472/solidity-function-successful-from-truffle-develop-but-fails-from-javascript